# Do open/visit + link collocate?

Tags: collocations

I looked up in Longman's and Oxford's collocation dictionaries for the following words but did not find any

- open + link
- visit + link

Are they not common enough to be recognized or are they unnatural at all? I am more interested in the verb ***open*** though. Do native speakers ever use the verb as in:

> ***Open*** the following link ...

or

> After ***opening*** the link you will get a list of all the websites ...

I am pretty sure that I could use *visit the following links* whether mentioned in the dictionaries or not. I am just not sure about **open**, and curious why **visit** not included in the collocations dictionaries

Comment: "Visiting a link" sure doesn't sound right. You may open/click a link, but you **visit the site** associated with the link. I suppose a lot of people say it though...

Answer (score 1):

When you do a web search for "[visit the links below](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22visit%20the%20links%20below%22%20site%3Auk&ia=web)" or "[visit the following links](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22visit%20the%20following%20links%22%20site%3Auk&ia=web)" (both searchers are restricted to the .uk domain) you will find many instances, including instances on websites of universities and public authorities.

A search for "open the links below" (within the .uk domain) also leads to many hits; "open the following links" appears to be less frequent.

(Note: I restricted my searches to the .uk domain to reduce the share of search results from non-native speakers of English in the overall search results.)

In technical standards, such as the W3C's Web Content Accessibility Guidelines, you will find the verb "visit" for links, URI's and pages. The verb "open" is mainly used for "web pages" and "windows", and occasionally also for links. (For example, search "visit" and "open" in the "Techniques for WCAG 2.0": https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/complete.html.)

Since dictionaries are descriptive, I assume they have not caught up yet.